# Using awk with column number in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, awk

I'm using a command like this to get some connections from `nf_conntrack`:

```
awk '($3 == "tcp") && ($6 != "TIME_WAIT") && ($10 == "dport=1234")' /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

How to use this command inside of a bash script and also add a script argument to it?
If I just do:

```
awk '($3 == "tcp") && ($6 != "TIME_WAIT") && ($10 == "dport=$1")' /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

It will suppose all `$1`,`$3`,`$6`,... are script arguments and fail.
How do I separate `awk` column numbers from the script arguments to use this command properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary, but it is the rule of thumb to explicitly declare variables you want to pass from your env to `awk`

```
awk -v myvar="dport=$1" '($3 == "tcp") && ($6 != "TIME_WAIT") && ($10 == myvar)' /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```